# Hello, sharp method returns me "Invalid Input"

Tags: node.js, nestjs, multer, sharp

when i use sharp function, i get "Invalid Input". Here is the code

```
import { BadRequestException, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as sharp from 'sharp'

@Injectable()
export class SharpPipe implements PipeTransform<Express.Multer.File, Promise<string>> {

    async transform(image: Express.Multer.File): Promise<string> {
        const originalName = path.parse(image.originalname).name;
        const filename = Date.now() + '-' + originalName + '.webp';

           await sharp(image.buffer)
               .resize(800)
               .webp({effort: 3})
               .toFile(path.join('uploads', filename));

        return filename;
    }

}
```

i know that a problem is into sharp method. Help me guys

Comment: Where are you using this pipe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer property is only valid on you are using the `MemoryStorage` for the multer. Set the multer init options with `{storage:multer.MemoryStorage()}` may fix your problem.